# Grails, Params from gsp to Controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm quit new to grails and took over another persons coding

I'm having problems with getting params from my gsp viewer to my groovy controller 
And when I get the right params it does not change to the right viewer and just goes back to the index sight

```
<td valign="top" class="value">
    <g:textField name="key" value="${key}" class="form-control" />
</td>

<button class="download">
    <g:link action="show"><g:message code="defualt.button.show.label" default="?Visa" /></g:link>
 </button>
```

Comment: what are the params you want to get to your controller? If you want to add params to your link, you have to use the `params`-attribute for your `g:link`-tag : https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/link.html

Comment: its the key value from my textField,
but with params in g:link it can not seem to find the value from my textfield

Answer (score 2):

Your Controller Code:

```
def key= params.key
```

Your GSP Code:

```
<g:form action="show">
<td valign="top" class="value">
    <g:textField name="key" value="${key}" class="form-control" />
    <g:submitButton name="download" value="download" />
</td>
</g:form>
```

Comment: As the answer here implies, a "link" will not pick up parameters from fields on the page, placing those fields within a form will include them as params in the action.